# Truthy and falsy values in Dart programming language

Tags: dart

I just stand in front of a very weird part in dart, I didn't find an answer on the internet, No truthy and falsy values in dart?!

for example,

```
const x = "foo";
void main(){
  if(x){
    print("x is set")
  }
}
```

In JavaScript we do this things very easily, how can I do that in Dart?!

Comment: Check this which might be useful http://shailen.github.io/blog/2012/11/16/booleans-in-dart/

Answer (score 2):

Dart is a statically typed language, so `x` is a String, and you can't check if a string is true or false.

if you want to check if `x` has a value or not, you can do the following

```
String x = 'hi';
if (x?.isNotEmpty ?? false) {
  print("x is set");
}
```

Comment: Being statically typed is independent of having truthy/falsey values.  C is statically typed but treats anything that does not compare equal to zero as true.

Answer (score -2):

After some researches, I've found that in order to check for a **dynamiclly** assigned variable, where in case you're not sure if the variable will be set to a number or a string for example, you **need** to check if the variable is not equal to null.

For example:

```
void main(){
var a;
  if(true){
    a = "The variable is set to string";
  }
  else if(false){
    a = 12; //the variable is set to a number
  }
  //Now, to check:
  if(a != null){
    print("A is set, WOW Dart is working! I thought it's garbage!");
  }
}
```

In case the both statements are false, the variable will still be a null.

Comment: this code is totally wrong.
the value of `a` will always be "The variable is set to string"

Comment: The first condition `if(true)` will always evaluate to `true` and `if(false)` will always evaluate to `false`. One should always compare the variable for the value in the condition like `if(a == true)`.